# Why questions are closed by N people and not only one

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

A question is sometimes closed for a number of reasons (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597747/are-there-any-reasons-to-still-use-svn-closed)), but often there are a bunch of users who *close* it. Why so many people - why the thread is not closed by the first moderator request in the 1st place?

Does a question needs N votes to be closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users with over [3,000 reputation points can cast close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), and after 5 close votes the question gets closed.

Real ["diamond" moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) can close questions immediately (eg: with one vote).

For more details:
[What is a "closed", “on hold”, or "duplicate" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)